# "How to edit" scroll bar doesn't reach the top

Tags: bug, edits, design, stack-exchange, scrolling

The vertical scrolling "How to edit" section doesn't scrolls up the top when editing a post here on meta-stackexchange. Take [for example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/231091/edit)

> [image]

They should reach the top so that we can refer it if required just like below example

> [image]

Comment: This got nothing to do with scrolling. voting to close as dupe of a better, more clear, report.